# Cutify this typescript 'groupBy' function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I found somewhere a 'groupBy' function for in use of my array manipulation.

Since I found it very annoying to have to sort before using groupBy, I modified the function somewhat to sort itself, but it has an ugly try catch. Why? Because the sort could be on a number or else on a string. 
Suggestions to do this without the try catch?? THANKS!

I call it like this: (code omitted for brevity)

```
 const temp =  groupBy(textMeta, (t)=> t.bookid).map( (group)=>
  ({'bookId': group.key, 
    'title':   'temporary',


 /**
 * @param list  Array to be grouped. 
 * @param the key that is used to group on
 */
export
function groupBy<T, KEY>(list:T[], func:(x:T)=>KEY): Group<T, KEY>[] {
  let res:Group<T, KEY>[] = [];
  let group:Group<T, KEY> = null;

  //UPDATE what about if (list.every(f => typeof  func(f) === 'number'))

  try {
    list.sort((a, b)=> Number.parseInt(func(a).toString()) - Number.parseInt(func(b).toString()));
  }
  catch (ex)
  {
    list.sort((a, b)=> func(a) > func(b) ? 1 : 
                      (func(a) < func(b) ? -1 : 0 )
                      );
  }
  list.forEach((o)=>{
      let groupName = func(o);
      if (group === null) {
          group = new Group<T, KEY>(groupName);
      }
      if (groupName != group.key) {
          res.push(group);
          group = new Group<T, KEY>(groupName);
      }
      group.members.push(o)
  });
  if (group != null) {
      res.push(group);
  }
  return res
}
```

Comment: What is the expected input and output? Can you create a working example on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/# ? If I paste your code there it shows a bunch of errors.

Comment: typescriptloang.org does not allow generics. Will not work.

Comment: [says who](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOJQPYFcAOAeAFQEYAaZAgJgD4BvAKAF866YsQExgMRkBzTXACEAnoTIBpAKIBNKgAoANsADOYAFzkA2gF0yrdhrkAPDQQCUyALxVkU6WY3ps+AhJlUdyesh-IFEMGQoCGVHARc3WU9LZB0AbjpfIICsKB5g5QSmIA)

Answer (score 0):

to all

> if (list.every(f => typeof  func(f) === 'number'))

works for me sufficiently.